# JqCloud (words with Custom/Given color)

Tags: javascript, jquery, tag-cloud, word-cloud

I am using JqCloud to Create Word Cloud,
It works fine and give expected Result.
My problem is i want to give text color which is Provided by user.

My Code is Like

```
var words = [
  {text: "Lorem", weight: 13},
  {text: "Ipsum", weight: 10.5},
  {text: "Dolor", weight: 9.4}  
];

$('#demo').jQCloud(words, {
  classPattern: null,
  colors: ["#800026", "#bd0026", "#e31a1c", "#fc4e2a", "#fd8d3c", "#feb24c", "#fed976", "#ffeda0", "#ffffcc"],
  fontSize: {
    from: 0.1,
    to: 0.02
  }
});
```

The above code assign color but its depend on priority,
I want to declare color in such way that cloud generate with given color.

Is there any way so that i can set text color.

```
ex. Lorem - Red(#FF0000)  
Ipsum- Green(#006600)  
Dolor - Blue(#0000FF)
```

Some thing Like or any other way

```
var words = [
  {text: "Lorem", weight: 13,Color:"#FF0000"},
  {text: "Ipsum", weight: 10.5,Color:"#006600"},
  {text: "Dolor", weight: 9.4 ,Color:"#0000FF"}  
];
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution for you ...

```
var words = [
    { text: "Lorem", weight: 13, color: "#FF0000" },
    { text: "Ipsum", weight: 10.5, color: "violet" },
    { text: "Dolor", weight: 9.4, color: "#0000FF" },
    { text: "Sit", weight: 8, color: "orange" },
    { text: "Amet", weight: 6.2, color: "#26FC32" },
    { text: "Consectetur", weight: 5, color: "#006600" },
    { text: "Adipiscing", weight: 5, color: "green" }
];

$("#demo").jQCloud(words);

setTimeout(function () {
    var obj = $("#demo").data("jqcloud");
    var data = obj.word_array;
    for (var i in data) {
        $("#" + data[i]["attr"]["id"]).css("color", data[i]["color"]);
    }
}, 100);
```

## DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/soundar24/1874zvdk/

Answer (score 2):

A bit late to the party...

I added this feature to jQCloud a few months ago and requested a merge.

https://github.com/mistic100/jQCloud/pull/20

https://github.com/mistic100/jQCloud

The dataset that you provided in your question will work, but "Color" needs to be lowercase, like this:

```
var words = [
  {text: "Lorem", weight: 13, color:"#FF0000"},
  {text: "Ipsum", weight: 10.5, color:"#006600"},
  {text: "Dolor", weight: 9.4 , color:"#0000FF"}  
];
```

No need to loop and modify the CSS of each element in Soundar R's example.  Just grab the latest code.

Comment: Thank u, will check and update our existing code if require.